# Share point web part, asynchronous processing on the server

Tags: sharepoint, asynchronous, web-parts

I am developing a web part which has to parse a list of files on the server side and to output a report. The problem is that this opperation can last for a big amount of time.

I have decided to make the processing of the files in a separate thread and to load the web part content instant with a message like "Loading...." when the results are parse an event will be fired up and the content of the web part will pe updated.

I have found a lot of posts with the following solution

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163587.aspx
- http://markitup.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=1fded0e9-e871-4e4a-a419-c1a770174cf1
  (the idea is the same)

PROBLEM IS that I don't have in my solution the .aspx file in which I can adjust the `Async="true"` parameter in the `@Page` directive.

Does anyone knows where is this file or how it can be added to be handled corectly by the web part.

P.S. I have tried to execute the task with a `BackgroundWorker` but it rises the same error as with `Page.RegisterAsyncTask`. The error is: *"Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting an asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true and an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to PreRenderComplete event."*

Answer (score 0):

WebParts can run asynchronously/multi-threaded. Register the appropriate event handlers via Page.RegisterAsyncTask. You'll specify the method that should be invoked asynchronously, as well as the callback method to which control will return once processing is complete.

http://daniellarson.wordpress.com/2006/06/26/asynchronous-webparts-in-asp-net-2-0/

http://daniellarson.wordpress.com/2006/07/16/asynchrounous-asp-net-webparts-for-sharepointmoss/

Comment: I have read this posts, but the PROBLEM remained. Read the part from my question about the error which apperes. The page tells me that the async mode is not true.

Also "async pages are NOT enabled with SharePoint 2007, this is a setting you’ll need to edit in your SiteTemplates aspx pages or change globally in web.config." Where are SiteTemplates situated? My Solution does not containg web.config.
In the post you can see "The code will also execute EITHER syncronously or asyncronously, depending on the async value of the page" I ***can't achieve this goal* (to set async value of the page)...

Comment: Just a note: Asynchronous does NOT always mean multi-threaded

Comment: Pierreten: I agree with you. It will be perfect to be multi-threaded, but if it is not possible just asynchronous will be enough.

ANY SOLUTIONS?????????